# flutter create pdf using syncfusion

Tags: flutter, pdf, syncfusion

hello i have created a flutter app and in that i m using this package to create a pdf https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf

i didnt know to add a pdf here so i m attaching a drive link for downloading or viewing the pdf

the pdf or the format i want in my pdf is below u can download it from below link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WR1U7fYmBn9Pm1FyXdXfFxEvVhKTU3mw/view?usp=sharing

so far i have created the below pdf u can download it from below link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WyyEANBgmDy6RGR82ZgznW4IWhp41th2/view?usp=sharing

i m just trying to create or attach the format from this pdf https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WR1U7fYmBn9Pm1FyXdXfFxEvVhKTU3mw/view?usp=sharing

this is the code i tried to create pdf

```
 Future<void> generateInvoice() async {
    //Create a PDF document.
    final PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
    //Add page to the PDF
    final PdfPage page = document.pages.add();
    //Get page client size
    final Size pageSize = page.getClientSize();
    //Generate PDF grid.
    final PdfGrid grid = PdfGrid();
    // //Add invoice footer
    drawFooter(page, pageSize);
    //Secify the columns count to the grid.
    grid.columns.add(count: 6);
    //Create the header row of the grid.
    final PdfGridRow headerRow = grid.headers.add(1)[0];
    //Set style
    headerRow.style.backgroundBrush = PdfSolidBrush(PdfColor(68, 114, 196));
    headerRow.style.textBrush = PdfBrushes.white;
    headerRow.cells[0].value = 'Product Image';
    headerRow.cells[1].value = 'Product Id';
    headerRow.cells[1].stringFormat.alignment = PdfTextAlignment.center;
    headerRow.cells[2].value = 'Product Name';
    headerRow.cells[3].value = 'Metal';
    headerRow.cells[4].value = 'Stone';
    headerRow.cells[5].value = 'Quantity';
    //Add rows
    for(int i = 0; i < _totalItems; i++){
      final PdfGridRow row = grid.rows.add();
      var imageResponse1 = await get(Uri.parse(photoArray[i]));
      row.cells[0].value = PdfBitmap(imageResponse1.bodyBytes.toList());
      row.cells[1].value = array[i];
      row.cells[2].value = nameArray[i];
      row.cells[3].value = metalArray[i];
      row.cells[4].value = stoneArray[i];
      row.cells[5].value = '1';
      grid.rows[i].height = 100;
    }
    grid.columns[2].width = 200;
    for (int i = 0; i < headerRow.cells.count; i++) {
      headerRow.cells[i].style.cellPadding =
          PdfPaddings(bottom: 5, left: 5, right: 5, top: 5);
    }
    //Apply the table built-in style
    grid.applyBuiltInStyle(PdfGridBuiltInStyle.listTable4Accent5);

    grid.draw(
        page: page,
        bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, page.getClientSize().width,
            page.getClientSize().height));
    //Save the PDF document
    final List<int> bytes = document.save();
    //Dispose the document.
    document.dispose();
    //Get external storage directory
    Directory directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory());
    //Get directory path
    String path = directory.path;
    print(path);
    //Create an empty file to write PDF data
    File file = File('$path/Output.pdf');
    //Write PDF data
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    setState(() {
      isApiCallProcess = false;
    });
    //Open the PDF document in mobile
    OpenFile.open('$path/Output.pdf');
  }

  //Draw the invoice footer data.
  void drawFooter(PdfPage page, Size pageSize) {
    final PdfPen linePen =
    PdfPen(PdfColor(142, 170, 219, 255), dashStyle: PdfDashStyle.custom);
    linePen.dashPattern = <double>[3, 3];
    //Draw line
    page.graphics.drawLine(linePen, Offset(0, pageSize.height - 100),
        Offset(pageSize.width, pageSize.height - 100));

    const String footerContent =
    // ignore: leading_newlines_in_multiline_strings
    '''\r\n\r\nAny Questions? shreennansharda@gmail.com Or 971529893336''';

    //Added 30 as a margin for the layout
    page.graphics.drawString(
        footerContent, PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 9),
        format: PdfStringFormat(alignment: PdfTextAlignment.right),
        bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(pageSize.width - 30, pageSize.height - 70, 0, 0));
  }
```

basically in my app when a user click on the download button the data should get download in the format given in the first link.

i tried to create the format but it is a little difficult so please help me to solve this!

please help!!

Thanks in advance!!!!

**update question**

i tried something but i could not add the grid to the 3rd column and the quantity in footer is coming on first page only

here the pdf i tried

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sw4cAu3D58ggUZTkI8GIJza06gUMs86E/view?usp=sharing

please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have created a simple sample to create a PDF document as you shared before. Please find the code example below,

```
  //Create a PDF document
  final PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
  //Add a new page
  final PdfPage page = document.pages.add();

  //Create a string format to set text alignment
  final PdfStringFormat format = PdfStringFormat(
      alignment: PdfTextAlignment.center,
      lineAlignment: PdfVerticalAlignment.middle);
  final PdfStringFormat middleFormat =
      PdfStringFormat(lineAlignment: PdfVerticalAlignment.middle);

  //Create padding, borders for PDF grid
  final PdfPaddings padding = PdfPaddings(left: 2);
  final PdfPen linePen = PdfPen(PdfColor(0, 0, 0), width: 2);
  final PdfPen lastRowBorderPen = PdfPen(PdfColor(0, 0, 0), width: 1);
  final PdfBorders borders = PdfBorders(
      left: linePen, top: linePen, bottom: linePen, right: linePen);
  final PdfBorders lastRowBorder = PdfBorders(
      left: linePen,
      top: linePen,
      bottom: lastRowBorderPen,
      right: linePen);

  //Create a new font
  final PdfFont font = PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 9);

  //Drawing the grid as two seperate grids

  //Create a grid
  final PdfGrid headerGrid = PdfGrid();
  //Set font for all cells
  headerGrid.style.font = font;
  //Add columns
  headerGrid.columns.add(count: 3);
  //Set column width
  headerGrid.columns[0].width = 80;
  headerGrid.columns[2].width = 80;
  //Add a row
  final PdfGridRow headerRow1 = headerGrid.rows.add();
  //Set row height
  headerRow1.height = 70;
  //Add cell value and style properties
  headerRow1.cells[0].value = 'COMPANY LOGO (ROUND)';
  headerRow1.cells[0].style.stringFormat = format;
  headerRow1.cells[1].value = 'SHREE NNANSHARDA JEWELLERY (LOGO)';
  headerRow1.cells[1].style.stringFormat = format;
  headerRow1.cells[1].columnSpan = 2;
  final PdfGridRow headerRow2 = headerGrid.rows.add();
  headerRow2.cells[0].value = '';
  headerRow2.cells[0].columnSpan = 3;
  headerRow2.height = 15;
  final PdfGridRow headerRow3 = headerGrid.rows.add();
  headerRow3.cells[0].value = 'PARTY NAME:';
  headerRow3.cells[0].style.stringFormat = middleFormat;
  headerRow3.cells[0].style.cellPadding = padding;
  headerRow3.cells[2].value = 'DATE:';
  headerRow3.cells[2].style.stringFormat = middleFormat;
  headerRow3.cells[2].style.cellPadding = padding;
  final PdfGridRow headerRow4 = headerGrid.rows.add();
  headerRow4.cells[0].value = '';
  headerRow4.cells[0].columnSpan = 3;
  headerRow4.height = 25;
  //Set border for all rows
  for (int i = 0; i < headerGrid.rows.count; i++) {
    final PdfGridRow headerRow = headerGrid.rows[i];
    if (i == headerGrid.rows.count - 1) {
      for (int j = 0; j < headerRow.cells.count; j++) {
        headerRow.cells[j].style.borders = lastRowBorder;
      }
    } else {
      for (int j = 0; j < headerRow.cells.count; j++) {
        headerRow.cells[j].style.borders = borders;
      }
    }
  }
  //Draw grid and get drawn bounds
  final PdfLayoutResult result =
      headerGrid.draw(page: page, bounds: const Rect.fromLTWH(1, 1, 0, 0))!;

  //Create a new grid
  PdfGrid contentGrid = PdfGrid();
  contentGrid.style.font = font;
  contentGrid.columns.add(count: 4);
  //Add grid header
  contentGrid.headers.add(1);
  contentGrid.columns[0].width = 40;
  contentGrid.columns[1].width = 140;
  contentGrid.columns[3].width = 80;
  //Get header and set values
  final PdfGridRow contentHeader = contentGrid.headers[0];
  contentHeader.cells[0].value = 'SR NO';
  contentHeader.cells[0].style.stringFormat = format;
  contentHeader.cells[0].style.borders = borders;
  contentHeader.cells[1].value = 'PRODUCT IMAGE';
  contentHeader.cells[1].style.stringFormat = format;
  contentHeader.cells[1].style.borders = borders;
  contentHeader.cells[2].value = 'PRODUCT DETAILS';
  contentHeader.cells[2].style.stringFormat = format;
  contentHeader.cells[2].style.borders = borders;
  contentHeader.cells[3].value = 'QUANTITY';
  contentHeader.cells[3].style.stringFormat = format;
  contentHeader.cells[3].style.borders = borders;
  //Add content rows
  contentGrid =
      _addContentRow('1', contentGrid, format, middleFormat, padding);
  contentGrid =
      _addContentRow('2', contentGrid, format, middleFormat, padding);
  contentGrid =
      _addContentRow('3', contentGrid, format, middleFormat, padding);
  contentGrid =
      _addContentRow('4', contentGrid, format, middleFormat, padding);
  contentGrid =
      _addContentRow('5', contentGrid, format, middleFormat, padding);
  //Add a new row
  final PdfGridRow totalRow = contentGrid.rows.add();
  totalRow.cells[0].value = 'TOTAL QUANTITY';
  //Set column span
  totalRow.cells[0].columnSpan = 3;
  totalRow.cells[0].style.stringFormat = format;
  totalRow.height = 25;
  //Set borders for all cells in grid
  for (int i = 0; i < contentGrid.rows.count; i++) {
    final PdfGridRow contentRow = contentGrid.rows[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < contentRow.cells.count; j++) {
      contentRow.cells[j].style.borders = borders;
    }
  }
  //Draw content grid based on the bounds calculated in first grid
  contentGrid.draw(
      page: result.page,
      bounds:
          Rect.fromLTWH(1, result.bounds.top + result.bounds.height, 0, 0));

  //Save PDF document
  final List<int> bytes = document.save();
  //Dispose the document
  document.dispose();

  //Get external storage directory
  Directory directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory())!;
  //Get directory path
  String path = directory.path;
  //Create an empty file to write PDF data
  File file = File('$path/Output.pdf');
  //Write PDF data
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
  //Open the PDF document in mobile
  OpenFile.open('$path/Output.pdf');

//Custom method to create content row and set style properties
PdfGrid _addContentRow(String srNo, PdfGrid grid, PdfStringFormat format,
    PdfStringFormat middleFormat, PdfPaddings padding) {
  //Add a row
  final PdfGridRow contentRow1 = grid.rows.add();
  //Set height
  contentRow1.height = 15;
  //Set values and style properties
  contentRow1.cells[0].value = srNo;
  contentRow1.cells[0].style.stringFormat = format;
  //Set row span
  contentRow1.cells[0].rowSpan = 6;
  contentRow1.cells[1].rowSpan = 6;
  contentRow1.cells[2].value = '';
  contentRow1.cells[3].rowSpan = 6;
  final PdfGridRow contentRow2 = grid.rows.add();
  contentRow2.cells[2].value = 'DESIGN NO-';
  contentRow2.cells[2].style.cellPadding = padding;
  contentRow2.cells[2].style.stringFormat = middleFormat;
  final PdfGridRow contentRow3 = grid.rows.add();
  contentRow3.cells[2].value = 'GROSS WEIGHT-';
  contentRow3.cells[2].style.cellPadding = padding;
  contentRow3.cells[2].style.stringFormat = middleFormat;
  final PdfGridRow contentRow4 = grid.rows.add();
  contentRow4.cells[2].value = 'DIAMOND CTS-';
  contentRow4.cells[2].style.cellPadding = padding;
  contentRow4.cells[2].style.stringFormat = middleFormat;
  final PdfGridRow contentRow5 = grid.rows.add();
  contentRow5.cells[2].value = 'GOLD COLOUR-';
  contentRow5.cells[2].style.cellPadding = padding;
  contentRow5.cells[2].style.stringFormat = middleFormat;
  final PdfGridRow contentRow6 = grid.rows.add();
  contentRow6.cells[2].value = '';
  contentRow6.height = 15;
  final PdfGridRow contentRow7 = grid.rows.add();
  contentRow7.cells[0].value = '';
  contentRow7.cells[0].columnSpan = 4;
  contentRow7.height = 5;
  return grid;
}
```

Please find the sample from https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/create_pdf_file-1346255899

And also find the output PDF sample from https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/samples-74335454.